# SharedPreferencs crashes program

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-debug

I'm making this program that requires a username to run. In the settings, the intent worked fine until I added the Shared Preferences code. I might have added it in the wrong place. Otherwise the intent was working absolutely fine. Also the share preferences is not saving the string. It keeps on crashing. Any ideas?

```
package com.XXX.XXX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Settings extends Activity{

EditText nameXML;
SharedPreferences filename;
public  String name;
String filenamename = "nameFile";
Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    nameXML = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    filename = getSharedPreferences(filenamename,0);
    String username = filename.getString("nameString", "Master Traders");
    nameXML.setHint(username);
    name = nameXML.getText().toString();
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Editor nameEditor = filename.edit();
            nameEditor.putString("nameString", name);
            nameEditor.commit();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

change to:

```
    Button save;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        save  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//this line is before onclicklistener.
 save.setOnclickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = nameXML.getText().toString(); 
            Editor nameEditor = filename.edit();
            nameEditor.putString("nameString", name);
            nameEditor.commit();
        }
    });
    }
```

You should post logcat the further see what the problem is. But most likely is due to what @Reid proposed. The new updated code is added.

Comment: Thanks but the SharedPreferences is not saving the name.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an editText and only supplying it with a hint, then attempting to get the contents from it all in the `onCreate()`.
You need to get the Text from the editText when the user has clicked save.
So try putting

```
name = nameXML.getText().toString();
```

Inside the onClickListener.

otherwise you're attempting to get a string from an empty editText.